# How to zoomin and zoomout an image with help of two different buttons in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am developing a Windows store app and I have an image on my XAML page and a plus and minus button.I want that when user click on plus button then the image should zoomin and zoomout when he click on minus button.With ScrollViewer i am able to do but,not with the buttons.Can anyone help please?

Comment: What is the problem of doing that with the buttons exactly?

Comment: I don't know what to put in the Button click event for zoomin and zoomout.I am trying to call the scrollviewer but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a ScrollViewer as you base:

```
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="MySCrollView"
    VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
    ZoomMode="Enabled">

    <Image />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Put following code in your click events.

zoom in:

```
MyScrollViewer.ChangeView(MyScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, MyScrollViewer.VerticalOffset, MyScrollViewer.ZoomFactor + 0.1f);
```

zoom out:

```
MyScrollViewer.ChangeView(MyScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, MyScrollViewer.VerticalOffset, MyScrollViewer.ZoomFactor - 0.1f);
```

0.1f is your zoom step. Probably you need to adjust the offset that you zoom centred.

Comment: It is not scrolling horizontally.

Comment: And I want that user should not be able to zoomout more than the original image.

Comment: If I would have one more button which shows the original image whenever user clicks on it.It does not depend whether image is zoomed in or not.How can i achieve that?

Comment: I would assume that you need to set the ZoomFactor to 1.

Comment: For scrollviewer,in my click event?

Comment: If I understood you right, then: MyScrollViewer.ChangeView(MyScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, MyScrollViewer.VerticalOffset, 1);

Comment: Image is not ZoomingIn fron the center.Any idea what should be the offset??